# ejecutar una accion en un formulario padre desde un boton en un formulario hijo

Tags: c#, windows-forms

buenas a todos quisiera saber como lograr lo que se expone en la pregunta, tengo un botón en un formulario hijo que me debe ejecutar un acción en el formulario padre pero no lo e conseguido

el formulario hijo lo abro en un panel del formulario padre

[image: form_padre]

y cuando abre el hijo quiero cerrar el formulario padre aun con el hijo adentro

Comment: Lo mejor es que uses delegados para comunicar entre formularios.

Comment: como @AntonioS.F.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Podrias mostrarnos que intentaste hasta ahora?

Comment: **y cuando abre el hijo quiero cerrar el formulario padre aun con el hijo adentro**
nunca lo he intentado pero si cierras el padre se cierran los hijos automaticamente, si dices que quieres abrir el hijo y en ese mismo instante cerrar hijo y padre que es lo que deseas hacer???